# Edit Profile: View data with ajax and javascript get error 404 Not Found

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, get

level: beginner

I've tried to view my user profile data from database to html page using ajax in javascript file. But I always get 404 Error. ***I want to view my user profile in the html form, so that user can update it.***

I don't know what's wrong with it.
Could you help me?
Here's my codes.

**Thank you.**

My php code in server side:
**newpass.php as a controller**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class newpass extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('newpass_model','npmod');
    }

    //to get the user profile
    public function read() {
        $iduser = $this->session->userdata('id');
        if(isset($iduser))
        echo json_encode($this->npmod->getByIdUser($iduser));
    }

    //to edit the user profile
    public function update() {
    $iduser = $this->session->userdata('id');
    $data = array(
        $nm = $this->input->post('nama'),
        $tmp = $this->input->post('tempat'),
        $tgl = $this->input->post('tanggal'),
        $jk = $this->input->post('jeniskelamin'),
        $tb = $this->input->post('tinggi'),
        $bb = $this->input->post('berat'),
        $gol = $this->input->post('golongan'),
        $kt = $this->input->post('kontak'),
        $nokt = $this->input->post('kontak_kel'),
        $emkt = $this->input->post('kontak_em')
    );
        if($$nm=='' || $tgl=='' || $jk=='' || $tb=='' || $bb=='' || $gol=='' || $kt=='' || $nokt=='' || $emkt=='')
        {
            echo "0";
        }
        else
        {
            $this->npmod->update($iduser,$data);
            echo "1";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

My php code in server side:
**newpass_model.php as a model**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class newpass_model extends CI_Model {      

    //to get the user profile
    function getByIdUser($iduser) {
        $iduser = intval( $iduser );

        $query = $this->db->where('iduser',$iduser)->limit( 1 )->get('pasien');

        if( $query->num_rows() > 0 ) {
            return $query->row();
        } else {
            return array();
        }
    }   

    //to edit the user profile
    public function update($iduser,$data) { 
        $this->db->where('iduser',$iduser);
        $this->db->update('pasien',$data);
   }
}
?>
```

My javascript code in client side:
**newpass.js**

```
/*Don't forget to add set_ip.js and jquery before you use this script in HTML page to make it work*/
var urlini = seturl();
var part= 'newpass/';

var readUrl   = urlini+part+'read',
    updateUrl = urlini+part+'update';

$( function() {  
    readUsers();
}); //end document ready

//to update profile
function update_profile() {

    name = /^([-a-z0-9_-]{5,50})+$/i.test($("#nama").val());
    bb = /^([-0-9_-])+$/i.test($("#berat").val());

    var form_reg =  $("input").val();
    if(form_reg == "")
    {
        alert("Semua data harus diisi.");
    }
    else if(!name || !bb)
    {
        alert("Terdapat kesalahan atau data kosong pada pengisian data.\nPastikan password Anda sesuai.");
    }
    else
    {
        $.post(urlini+part+'update',
        $('#edit_profile').serialize(),function(msg){
        if(msg == '0')
        {
            alert("Masih ada data yang kosong.");
        }
        else if(msg == '1')
        {
            alert("Data berhasil disimpan!");
            window.location="home.html";
        }
    });
    }
}

function readUsers() {
$.ajax({
        url: readUrl,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function( response ) {

                $( '#nama' ).val( response.nama);
                $( '#tempat' ).val( response.tempat);
                $( '#tanggal' ).val( response.tanggal);
                $( '#jeniskelamin' ).val( response.jeniskelamin);
                $( '#tinggi' ).val( response.tinggi);
                $( '#berat' ).val( response.berat);
                $( '#golongan' ).val( response.golongan);
                $( '#kontak' ).val( response.kontak);
                $( '#kontak_kel' ).val( response.kontak_kel);
                $( '#kontak_em' ).val( response.kontak_em);
                //--- assign id to hidden field ---
                $( '#userId' ).val( response.id );
            }
    });
} // end readUsers
```

My javascript code in client side:
**set_ip.js**

```
//where the set the domain name
var ip = 'localhost';
var urlnya = 'http://'+ip+'/diabet_console/';
function seturl()
{    
    return urlnya;
}
```

My html code in client side:
**settings.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style1.css" />

 <link href="date/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="date/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="date/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="date/js/kendo.web.min.js"></script>
    <script src="date/js/console.js"></script>
    <script src="jq/proses/set_ip.js"></script>
    <script src="jq/proses/newpass/newpass.js"></script>
    <script src="jq/proses/script.js"></script>

<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        // create DatePicker from input HTML element
        $("#tanggal").kendoDatePicker({
        start: "date",
        depth: "year",
        format: "dd/MM/yyyy",
        });
    });
    </script>
<title>edc - e diabet consult</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 align="center">Edit Profile</h1>
<p align="center" class="navigation">
<a href="home.html" title="Kembali ke CPanel">
<img src="ico/home.png">
</a>
<a href="pengaturan.html" title="Change Password">
<img src="ico/pass.png">
</a>
<a href="ranges.html" title="Set Target Range">
<img src="ico/setting.png">
</a>
</p>
<div id="updateDialog">
<form id="edit_profile" action="" method="post">
<p width="50%" align="center">
<strong>Nama Pasien</strong><br>
<input type="text" maxlength="350" id="nama" name="nama"><br>

<strong>Tempat Lahir</strong><br>
<input type="text" maxlength="350" id="tempat" name="tempat"><br>

<strong>Tanggal Lahir</strong><br>
<input type="text" maxlength="350" id="tanggal" name="tanggal" value="01-02-2013"><br>
<br>
<strong>Jenis Kelamin</strong><br>
<input class="float" type="radio" id="jeniskelamin" name="jeniskelamin" value="L">Laki-Laki 
<input class="float" type="radio" id="jeniskelamin" name="jeniskelamin" value="P">Perempuan<br><br>

<strong>Tinggi Badan (cm)</strong><br>
<input type="text" id="tinggi" name="tinggi"><br>

<strong>Berat Badan (kg)</strong><br>
<input type="text" id="berat" name="berat" value=''><br>

<strong>Golongan Darah</strong><br>
<input class="float" type="radio" id="golongan" name="golongan" value="A">A 
<input class="float" type="radio" id="golongan" name="golongan" value="B">B
<input class="float" type="radio" id="golongan" name="golongan" value="AB">AB
<input class="float" type="radio" id="golongan" name="golongan" value="O">O<br>
<br>

<strong>Kontak Pasien</strong><br>
<input type="text" id="kontak" name="kontak" value=''><br>

<strong>Kontak Keluarga</strong><br><br>
<strong>No.Telepon</strong><br>
<input type="text" id="kontak_kel" name="kontak_kel" value=''><br>

<strong>Email</strong><br>
<input type="text" id="kontak_em" name="kontak_em" value=''><br>

<input type="submit" value="Simpan" id="simpan" class="button" onclick="update_profile()">
<input type="reset" value="Reset" class="button">

</p>
<br><br/>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can u copy the link when the 404 error occurs and post it here. You can do this as suggested by devesh

Comment: Here's the link http://localhost/www/jq/process/newpass/newpass.js

Comment: I found the one I'm messing around with. ***I've forgot to give the right javascript source***. But still, the data that appear only just several of it (just: nama and kontak), I don't know how I can view all data. Could you help me? **Thank you very much**

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the fiddler to check what is the URL being requested through AJAX call or developer tool in chrome or IE. In IE you can use F12 and under developer tool use Network and click on Start capture and call your ajax function. Check the URL is correct or not or the expected one or not.

Comment: how to "use the fiddler to check what is the URL being requested through AJAX call"? coz I only use Ctrl+Shift+j. I have no idea about fiddler. thanks :)

Comment: Please use IE option F12 (Developer tool) if you have latest IE version running. http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ is where you can go for Fiddler but i think IE developer tool itself is handy

Comment: I had used chrome, and try to check with Ctrl+Shift+j -> the Network button-> "XHR" sub-button, and nothing appear. In console GET http://localhost/www/jq/process/newpass/newpass.js 404 (Not Found) settings.html:14
Btw, I don't use IE, thanks anyway...

Comment: @ganeshrj I'm new at this, the url I used is the one that other's module in the whole program  used. The truth, I make it as my senior's wrote in other module. Could you give me a pointer on URL here? coz I'm really confuse. thanks for your help....

Comment: Try to alert the readUrl before calling the AJAX method to see what is the URL is going to be called . I doubt URL is having some logical issue

Comment: @Devesh I found the one I'm messing around with. I've forgot to give the right javascript source. I'm sorry to bother you, and thank you for your help. ^_^

Comment: I found the one I'm messing around with. ***I've forgot to give the right javascript source***. But still, the data that appear only just several of it (just: nama and kontak), I don't know how I can view all data. Could you help me? **Thank you very much**

Comment: Tell me when you are missing the data , while Getting or while posting the data after clicking update and where are you missing it ( in case of update ) on client side or server side

Comment: @Devesh **I just load the html page**, I'm hoping that the data will appear in the form, so that user can update it. But the data that appear only two: nama and kontak. _I have not yet tried my update button coz my data still not viewed correctly._ thanks

Comment: Please make sure that you are getting all the names correctly in json response . like response.jeniskelamin , in the json response you should have same key name jeniskelamin . You can use the chrome Network to see the response also , after the GET Ajax is called or you can alert the response.

Answer (score 0):

```
function readUsers() {
$.ajax({
        url: readUrl,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST', // is missing in your ajax call also it might type:get if form  submission is get
```

Comment: @ganeshj I made the type: post and form method="post" and I made the type: get and form method="get" . I do as you wrote, still nothing happened.

Comment: type: is only determine how the data will be posted to the server , if you do not give any thing it will be GET , but this will be never be the reason for the 404 error . It can only come from url is being configured incorrectly